# Count 2-month-active-people

Tags: sql, postgresql

So I need to do a query from the orders table which will count for each week the number of people who made an order in the past 4 weeks and also in a period of 4-8 weeks before. So basically who ordered in this rolling month and the previous rolling month simultaneously.
I was trying different stuff but was able only to do this for a month granularity using

```
select
  month,
  count(client)
from
  orders
union all
select
  month + interval '1 month',
  count(client)
from
  orders
```

And then I sum counts for each month. But with weeks it will be 8 unions so please God no. Do you have any ideas on how to do this?
I'm using Postgres. Thank you!

Example data

```
|client_id|created   |
|:--------|:--------:|
|d        |2021-08-31|
|e        |2021-08-31|
|a        |2021-09-05|
|f        |2021-09-05|
|c        |2021-09-12|
|d        |2021-09-18|
|e        |2021-09-27|
|f        |2021-09-27|
|g        |2021-09-30|
|d        |2021-10-04|
|e        |2021-10-04|
|f        |2021-10-04|
|a        |2021-10-11|
|f        |2021-10-11|
```

client id - uuid, created - timestamp, both not nulls

Expected results:

```
|weekMonday|2monthActi|
|:---------|:--------:|
|2021-09-20|-         |
|2021-09-27|-         |
|2021-10-04|2         |
|2021-10-11|4         |
```

2021-09-20 and 2021-09-27 - only one month passed. 2021-10-04 - d and e users ordered in this(2021-09-05 - 2021-10-04) and previous(2021-08-05 - 2021-09-04) rolling month at least once. 2021-10-11 - d,e,a and f users ordered in this (2021-09-12 - 2021-10-11) and previous (2021-08-12 - 2021-09-11) rolling month at least once

Comment: Welcome to the SO community. The community will help with you issues but has certain expectations from you. Please take a few minuets to take the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour/) and to review [ask]. In particular post table description (ddl), sample test data, as text - **no images**. Even better create a [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13) with the preceding.  Also post the expected results of that data.

Comment: @Belayer Thanks, didn't know that. Can I leave a Google Drive link to .csv?

Comment: A like to Google drive *may be acceptable*, but not preferred (fiddle or text much better) and **absolutely not 114k rows**.  Typical a dozen to 20 rows, virtually never more than 50.   Also you need to post the **expected results** which you do not have. Pick a few rows that demonstrate your issue and post then and the results you want. If not creating a fiddle. then you need to include table definitions (ddl).

Comment: Keep in mind you are asking professionals who have their own jobs and tasks to volunteer their time for help  with your issue.  It benefits you to spend some time to make it as simple as possible to do that. The more the community needs to work at it the less likely you'll get a satisfactory answer.

Comment: @Belayer Hey! I added sample data and expected results, DDL is pretty obvious I added it too though. Is it better now?